# hot-replace debugging with maven on jboss

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, maven

I'm currently using jboss/maven/eclipse to debug a web app. I've enabled remote debugging in the jboss `run.conf` file and then use `mvn war:inplace` to compile and with that I can successfully add a breakpoint and step through code.

However I remember a while back using Tomcat I was able to hotswap or hot-replace a java class by making changes, saving it and then having the debugger re-enter the method. I'm thinking there has to be a way to do this but don't know how.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from hot-swapping code as long as the new code is correct (no compilation problems there) and it doesn't change signatures (no class renames, method renames, field renames, type changes, etc.) The other problem might be related to the JVM you are using, it might not support hot-swapping, although I doubt it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [JBoss Tools](http://www.jboss.org/tools) Eclipse plugin, or if all else fails, JRebel (however, its not free).